# How do I properly pass an XML doc to SQLServer via a Spring JDBC Template?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I am having problems trying to do an SQL insert with XML as one of the params.

My platform:
Java 7
Win 7
JTDS JDBC driver
SQL Server
Spring JDBC 4.0

I tried this (from an example in the Spring docs):

```
Jdbc4SqlXmlHandler handler = new Jdbc4SqlXmlHandler();
SqlXmlValue value = handler.newSqlXmlValue(doc_);                           
return _jdbcTemplate.update(createSQL, new Object[] {userID_, value});
```

doc_ is an org.w3c.dom.Document passed into a method

createSQL is:

```
private final static String createSQL = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (USER_ID, DOC) values (?, ?) ";
```

I get a null pointer exception in AbstractJdbc4SqlXmlValue.cleanup() (in Jdbc4SqlXmlHandler) when it calls free on the xmlObject var:

```
public void cleanup() {
  try {
this.xmlObject.free();
  }
  catch (SQLException ex) {
    throw new DataAccessResourceFailureException("Could not free SQLXML object", ex);
  }
}
```

xmlObject is null, but there is a reference to the document within Jdbc4SqlXmlHandler

I am doing something wrong, but I don't see it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: You don't.

JTDS is a JDBC 3 driver and does not support SQLXML values.

SQLXML values are only supported in JDBC 4.

Therefore I have to use the MS JDBC driver.